# PL/SQL - Cannot convert string to desired date format using to_date()

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a string like "01-JAN-15 13:05:01". I used to_date() function to convert the string to date format and store it to a date field. However, the time value stored is not correct, which is "01/01/2015 04:12:43 PM". I used to_char() function to show the value of the converted date, but the returned value does not have any problem.

Input(String): 01-JAN-15 13:05:01

Desired Output(Date): 01/01/15 01:05:01 PM

Actual Output(Date): 01/01/15 04:12:43 PM

**Code for conversion:**

```
select to_date('01-JAN-15 13:05:01', 'dd-mon-yy hh24:mi:ss') into result_date from dual;
```

**to_char()**

```
to_char(result_date, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss');
```

**UPDATE:**

```
whenever sqlerror exit 99 ROLLBACK;
set echo on;
set verify on;
set serverout on;
declare
    result_date date;
begin
    select to_date('01-JAN-15 13:05:01', 'dd-mon-yy hh24:mi:ss') into result_date from dual;
    insert into temp_table values (result_date);
    commit;
end;
```

Comment: So, do you have a small but complete PL/SQL block that I can run that will reproduce your problem?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am sorry that I do not have the entire block for execution, but @Naveen Chappa 's answer below is similar.

Comment: Well then it sounds like something else, not mentioned in this question, changed your data.  Without something we can reproduce, there is not much we can do for you.

Comment: I just updated the code. The problem happened at the insert statement.

Comment: what is error and structure of temp table?

Comment: I can think of at least two ways this can occur, but I need some questions answered first. #1) what is the data type of `TEMP_TABLE.RESULT_DATE`? #2) what triggers are defined on `TEMP_TABLE`? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Above code should not give a problem. I ran below code snippet and gave me the expected result. Double check once if you are using above code only.

```
DECLARE
result_date DATE;
BEGIN

select to_date('01-JAN-15 13:05:01', 'dd-mon-yy hh24:mi:ss') INTO result_date from dual;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(to_char(result_date, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM'));

END;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. In fact, the problem happened when the result_date is stored to database, but not dbms_output.put_line. The value output by dbms_output.put_line is correct, but the time value changed in database.

Comment: can I see that code? May be a third eye can find the root cause.

Comment: I just updated the code. The problem happened at the insert statement.

Comment: @CodeEater I don't think insert statement is causing the problem here. There could be some other issue.